# The numbers a and b are simple numbers between them.

Tags: prime-numbers

The numbers a and b are simple numbers between them. They have no common divisors other than number 1. We know that a/b=1,(3). Find a^2-b^2.

So I tried a=1,(3)*b and then substituted into the expression. [1,(3)b-b][1,(3)b+b]
But it didn't lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** From $\frac ab=1,333333333\ldots=\frac43$, you deduce that $4a=3b$. Now, use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.